# ReSTful design: return an empty object as a template for create new form

Tags: rest, restful-url

My question is straighforward - I think.

Currently the following Uris exist:

```
http://someserver/service/item           GET   returns all items  
http://someserver/service/item           POST  creates a new item  
http://someserver/service/item/{id}      GET   returns item with id {id}  
http://someserver/service/item/{id}      PUT   updates item with {id}
```

What I would like to do is return a blank 'item', like a template for creating new items which contains a list of the object parameters, their types, required or not.  The reason for this is I would like to build a generic jquery 'create new' plugin completely ignorant of the data structure, which I could apply to all my new objects.

What is the best way to implement this?

I hope this makes sense and thanks for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do pretty much the same thing.  I include a link in my "list of items" resource that you  can POST to.  The response is a template of a new item.  Arguably you could also do a GET to retrieve the template, but I use the opportunity to assign a new Id to the item so my request is not idempotent.

Comment: ahhh - I see!  So you do an empty POST which creates a new object with an id and then send that back in the response and then do a PUT against the newly created object??  Do you include metadata in the response object indicating the parameter datatype, max length etc?

Comment: @jimjim  My response contains a link to a metadata document with information on datatypes, validation information, data binding, etc.  That way the client can cache the metadata information.  No need to include the information in every instance document.  Make sure you use the Location header to provide the URL of the newly created resource.

Answer (score 12):

I understand an answer provided by Darrel but I would respectfully argue against it.

It seems to me that this template object (resource) is an important part of your application because you want to make it generic. It's a first class citizen resource and we're talking about REST, so it should be given a corresponding treatment. I should be able to GET the template resource, it shouldn't be "hidden" behind POST.

```
GET http://someserver/service/item/template
```

Then you can also introduce versioning and variability much more easily when you have a resource accessible via GET.

Comment: :-) I carefully avoided providing a sample URI to the endpoint, as what the endpoint looks like is not so relevant.  It's the rel="create|new|template|whatever" in the list document that allows me to discover the URI that is critical.  If you want to name the URI ../template that is perfectly fine.  I use POST because I generate and increment an id that is stored in my database.  If you use GUIDs for Ids then GET would work just fine.